# Implement a draggable element with inertia

Tags: drag, famous-engine

I've just stumbled upon the new famous 0.5 release and things seem to be quite different (looking good). I want to implement a draggable element with inertia, but I can't figure it out by looking at the new docs.

Can anyone give me some tip on how to do this?

Comment: Have you been able to setup a draggable element yet? If so, can you post what you have so far?

Comment: Hello talves, unfortunately no, the new 0.5 is so different I'm still learning it, and I didn't yet find an example of implementing dragging. I did try a GestureHandler with gestures.on('drag', callback); which doesn't actually move the object but gives me the interaction data. I thought of ways to use this data to move the object and add inertia but I would like to learn how to do this properly, not just experiment on my own as I am "green" to the 0.5 release.

Comment: We are all "green" right now on the new engine. :) You are definitely on the right track with how to drag an item. Let me throw together a quick example of Dragging a surface.

Comment: That would be great, thanks talves

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of using the `GestureHandler` to track the start, move and end of a drag in the famous engine. The `Position` component will place our node with respect to the delta of our drag event. Notice how the `node` is passed to the `GestureHandler` to track our drag events.

**Warning:** As of this posting, the engine is still in Beta (0.5.2), so there is an edge case issue with trying to drag too close to the outside of the element. It may have to do with the default interval of render updates.

```js
var rootScene = FamousEngine.createScene('body');
var rootNode = rootScene.addChild();
rootNode.setAlign(0.5, 0.5);

function Draggable(root) {
  this.node = root;
  this.node
    .setProportionalSize(0.5, 0.5)
    .setMountPoint(0.5, 0.5);

  this.position = new Position(this.node);
  console.log(this.position);

  var base = (Math.random() * 360) | 0;

  this.el = new DOMElement(this.node, {
    properties: {
      'textAlign': 'center',
      'color': 'white',
      'fontSize': '30px',
      'lineHeight': '40px',
      'background': 'hsl(' + ((base += 37) % 360) + ',40%,50%)',
      'cursor': 'pointer'
    }
  });

  this.el.setContent('Drag Me');

  var gestures = new GestureHandler(this.node, [{
    event: 'drag',
    callback: drag.bind(this)
  }]);

  function drag(e) {
    //console.log('drag', e.status, e);
    switch (e.status) {
      case 'start':
        console.log('start drag', this.position.getValue());
        break;
      case 'end':
        console.log('end drag', this.position.getValue());
        break;
      case 'move':
        var d = e.centerDelta;

        console.log('move drag', this.position.getValue(), d);
        var pos = this.position.getValue();
        this.position.set(pos.x + d.x, pos.y + d.y, pos.z);
        break;
    }
  }
}

var dragger = new Draggable(rootNode);
FamousEngine.init();
```

#### Run the snippet example

```js
var DOMElement = famous.domRenderables.DOMElement;
var Position = famous.components.Position;
var FamousEngine = famous.core.FamousEngine;
var GestureHandler = famous.components.GestureHandler;

var rootScene = FamousEngine.createScene('body');
var rootNode = rootScene.addChild();
rootNode.setAlign(0.5, 0.5);

function Draggable(root) {
  this.node = root;
  this.node
    .setProportionalSize(0.5, 0.5)
    .setMountPoint(0.5, 0.5);

  this.position = new Position(this.node);
  console.log(this.position);

  var base = (Math.random() * 360) | 0;

  this.el = new DOMElement(this.node, {
    properties: {
      'textAlign': 'center',
      'color': 'white',
      'fontSize': '30px',
      'lineHeight': '40px',
      'background': 'hsl(' + ((base += 37) % 360) + ',40%,50%)',
      'cursor': 'pointer'
    }
  });

  this.el.setContent('Drag Me<hr>');

  var gestures = new GestureHandler(this.node, [{
    event: 'drag',
    callback: drag.bind(this)
  }]);

  function drag(e) {
    //console.log('drag', e.status, e);
    switch (e.status) {
      case 'start':
        console.log('start drag', this.position.getValue());
        break;
      case 'end':
        console.log('end drag', this.position.getValue());
        break;
      case 'move':
        var d = e.centerDelta;

        console.log('move drag', this.position.getValue(), d);
        var pos = this.position.getValue();
        this.position.set(pos.x + d.x, pos.y + d.y, pos.z);
        break;
    }
  }
}

var dragger = new Draggable(rootNode);
FamousEngine.init();
```

```css
html,
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  body {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-perspective: 0;
    perspective: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico?v=1" type="image/x-icon">
<meta name="description" content="Draggable Famous@0.5.2">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.5.2/famous.min.js"></script>
```